# How to compare the rows of two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to compare two columns of different data frames to create a new data frame. If the value of the row of the first col is less than the second, it will add a 1 to the new column. When the value is greater, it will add a 2 and so on.

I'll give you an example. I have this df

```
df1 <- data.frame(col=c(1,seq(1:9),9,10))
# col
# 1    1
# 2    1
# 3    2
# 4    3
# 5    4
# 6    5
# 7    6
# 8    7
# 9    8
# 10   9
# 11   9
# 12  10
```

And this one, which has less rows

```
df2<-data.frame(col2=c(3,6,8))
#    col2
# 1    3
# 2    6
# 3    8
```

Now, my desire output would be something similar to this:

```
#      col3
# 1     1
# 2     1
# 3     1
# 4     2
# 5     2
# 6     2
# 7     3
# 8     3
# 9     4
# 10    4
# 11    4
# 12    4
```

I know this is a very basic question, but I'm not getting how to do this easily withouth using a for loop. I though about using `!unique()` to select the first element and see if its in the second with `%in%`but don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I'm not getting the explaining with the output example you put there. If you have two different size columns, how is the match? You are comparing the first row of the first column with the first row of the second, then the second rows in both, then the third and so on? What happens when the shortest column runs out of rows?

Comment: @Ghost Sorry for such a bad explanation. It is actually a "translation" of a SAS code. What I am looking for is to make a merge of the two columns, where, if in df2 the first number is a 4, of df1, all the minors under 4 get into a single category 1. The following ones in 2 ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think this would work:

```
apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) 1 + sum(x >= df2$col2))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

We use `apply` to iterate over the rows of `df1`, and then check the value in each row to see how it compares to `col2` in `df2`.

A dplyr alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    rowwise() %>% # group over each row
    mutate(col3 = 1 + sum(col >= df2$col2))

     col  col3
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1
 2     1     1
 3     2     1
 4     3     2
 5     4     2
 6     5     2
 7     6     3
 8     7     3
 9     8     4
10     9     4
11     9     4
12    10     4
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this can hellp you

```
z <- rep(F,nrow(df1))
z[c(1,df2$col2+1)]<- T
df1$col3 <- cumsum(z)
```

which gives

```
> df1
   col col3
1    1    1
2    1    1
3    2    1
4    3    2
5    4    2
6    5    2
7    6    3
8    7    3
9    8    4
10   9    4
11   9    4
12  10    4
```